# How best should I delete this user

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, user-account

I'm new to OSX and tried to create a user from the terminal which I no longer need and which I named incorrectly.

I see I can delete the user in System Preferences > Users & Groups but do I need to delete them from the terminal instead as this is where I created them?  If I delete them from the terminal what commands should I use?

Below are the commands I used to create the user:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/www-data UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . -create /Users/www-data RealName "Lucius Q. User"
sudo dscl . -create /Users/www-data UniqueID "1010"
sudo dscl . -create /Users/www-data PrimaryGroupID 80
sudo dscl . -create /Users/www-data NFSHomeDirectory /Users/www-data
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `sudo dscl . -delete /Users/www-data` ? You might also want to delete /Users/www-data with `rm -rf /Users/www-data`.

Comment: `delete: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)`